# Fancy sliding form with more validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am using  this [fancy sliding box](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/07/fancy-sliding-form-with-jquery/) and having some problem with validation.It has default validation for checking where a field is empty or not but i want to add some more validation like two specific fields are  equal or not or the length of a specific field is within the desired length or not.I have edited the code but facing a problem that is when a previous navigation field has any error it is also adding  error class for  the next navigation though it was filled correctly.
Here is my code(Be noted i don't know jquery well) :

```
function validateStep(step) {
     if(step == fieldsetCount) return;

     var error = 1;
     var hasError = false;      

    $('#formElem').children(':nthchild('+parseInt(step)+')')
        .find(':input:not(button)')
        .each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var valueLength = jQuery.trim($this.val()).length;

            //i don't know how to generate a specific field value using this keyword
            var pas=$('#myPassword').val().length;
            var pas1=$('#myPassword').val();
            var pas2=$('#VerifyPassword').val();

            var pin1=$('#mPin').val();
            var pin2=$('#vVPin').val();
            var pas_ok=1;

            if(pas1 != pas2 || pin1 ! =pin2 || pas < 5 ) {
                pas_ok=0;
            }

            if(valueLength == '' || pas_ok==0) {
                hasError = true;
                $this.css('background-color','#FFEDEF');
            } else {
                $this.css('background-color','#FFFFFF');
            }
    });

    var $link = $('#navigation li:nth-child(' + parseInt(step) + ') a');
    $link.parent().find('.error,.checked').remove();

    var valclass = 'checked';

    if(hasError) {
        error = -1;
        valclass = 'error';
    }

    $('<span class="'+valclass+'"></span>').insertAfter($link);

    return error;
}
```

Here is my form:

```
<div id="steps"> 
    <form id="formElem" name="formElem" action="" method="post" >
        <fieldset class="step">
            <legend>Account</legend>
            <p> 
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="myPassword" id="myPassword" value="<?=$myPassword;?>" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF  />
            </p>
            <p> 
                <label for="password"> Verify Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="VerifyPassword" id="VerifyPassword" value="<?=$VerifyPassword;?>" />
            </p>
            <p> 
                <label for="password"> Your Personal Pin </label>
                <input type="pin" name="mPin" id="mPin" value="<?=$mPin;?>" />
            </p>
            <p> 
                <label for="password"> Verify Personal Pin </label>
                <input type="pin" name="vVPin" id="vVPin" value="<?=$vVPin;?>" />
            </p>        
        </fieldset>
    </form>        
</div>
```

Comment: error!. change to: `parseInt(step,10) pas_ok===0 pin1 != pin2`

Comment: why parseInt(step,10)?

Comment: **parseInt(string,radix)**. radix: A number (from 2 to 36) that represents the numeral system to be used. **Note:** the default is the decimal radix (10). **Note:** Only the first number in the string is returned!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is checking all input fields for every each cycle again completeley. `.each()` gives you one input at a time. What you want to do is differentiate them via the input's respective `id` and then run the checks. The following code checks the length of all 4 input fields and marks them red if their length is zero and in case of the two verify input fields it also checks whether they are the same as their original input fields. The code is untested but you should get the idea.

```
$('#formElem').children(':nthchild('+parseInt(step)+')')
    .find(':input:not(button)')
    .each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var value = $this.val();
        var valueLength = jQuery.trim(value).length;

        var pas_ok = 1;
        var id = $this.attr("id");
        if (id === 'VerifyPassword') {
            var password = $('#myPassword').val();
            var vPassword = value;
            if (password !== vPassword)
                pas_ok = 0;
        } else if (id === 'vVPin') {
            var pin = $('#mPin').val()
            var vPin = value;
            if (pin !== vPin || pin.length < 5)
                pas_ok = 0;
        }

        if(valueLength === 0 || pas_ok === 0) {
            hasError = true;
            $this.css('background-color','#FFEDEF');
        } else {
            $this.css('background-color','#FFFFFF');
        }
    });
```

On a side note: Always use `===` instead of `==` if you compare something in javascript.

Comment: still same problem  "when a previous navigation field has any error it is also adding 'error' class in the next navigation though it was filled correctly." I didn't include the whole code so you can give a look here http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/07/fancy-sliding-form-with-jquery/

Comment: Don't know why,didn't work 1st time,but now working!Can you tell me how can i show image beside every field which has error ? and how can i remove  error background color(" $this.css('background-color','#FFEDEF'); ") instantly(live) when user corrects his error?

Comment: You should create new questions for these two, this is a different topic.